# Caminho entre 2 nos de um grafo usando menor numero de arestas coloridas

Tags: algoritmo, grafo

Estou tentando resolver [este](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1908) problema de programação.

Em resumo, o problema descreve diversas linhas de ônibus como um grafo não direcionado e fala que a passagem de um ônibus custa 1 real. Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como posso obter o menor custo em reais que sai de um no A para o no B ?

Nao consegui pensar em nenhuma estratégia usando uma busca em largura.

Nesse exemplo abaixo o menor valor para sair de A para B seria 2 reais. 1 real com uma passagem pela linha vermelha e outro real por uma passagem da linha azul.
[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você deve perceber no problema é que o custo entre as diversas linhas de ônibus é sempre `1`, então você não precisa nem mesmo utilizar o *algoritmo de Dijkstra* ou qualquer outro algoritmo de caminho mais curto genérico. Uma simples [Busca em Largura](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busca_em_largura) é o suficiente e mais rápida.

O segundo ponto importante é como construir seu grafo. Pelo enunciado do problema você consegue perceber que um Câmpus é ligado à  **X** outros campi por uma linha de ônibus, a qual você pode utilizar por tempo indefinido (desde que não saia da linha) para andar entre todos os campi conectados por tal linha. O que isso lhe diz é: **todos os vértices (os campi) de uma linha de ônibus têm acesso a todos os outros vértices, ou seja, são conectados no grafo, com arestas de peso `1`**.

Pegando a entrada de exemplo do problema:

```
9 4
6 2 3 4 6 7 9
4 1 3 4 5
3 8 3 4
2 9 8
```

Na segunda linha temos `2 3 4 6 7 9` (podemos ignorar o `6` aqui, pois ele só é utilizado para informar quantos vértices estão presentes na linha). Todos esses vértices apresentados podem chegar a qualquer um dos outros vértices pagando apenas um preço de `1`, então a representação dessas conexões em uma matriz de adjacência fica da seguinte forma:

```
   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
    --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
 1 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |

 2 |   |   | T | T |   | T | T |   | T |

 3 |   | T |   | T |   | T | T |   | T |

 4 |   | T | T |   |   | T | T |   | T |

 5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |

 6 |   | T | T | T |   |   | T |   | T |

 7 |   | T | T | T |   | T |   |   | T |

 8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |

 9 |   | T | T | T |   | T | T |   |   |
```

onde `T` indica que há uma aresta conectando dois vértices, e a ausência de `T` indica que não é possível chegar de um vértice a outro (**esse grafo representa apenas as conexões dadas pela primeira linha de ônibus do exemplo!**).

**Resumindo**: na hora de ler a entrada do problema, construa seu grafo de forma que todos os Campi de uma linha tenham acesso a todos os outros Campi da mesma linha. E execute uma Busca em Largura sobre o grafo. Isso lhe dará a resposta correta.

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta não tem uma resposta simples porque este problema de grafos não é simples.

Você deve usar algum algoritmo que resolva o "Problema do Caminho Mínimo" (inglês: *Shortest path problem*).

Não sei qual dos dois seria mais rápido em seu caso, então, tente um dos dois:

1. Dijkstra: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Dijkstra
2. A*: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_A*

Se você pesquisar em inglês, seria mais fácil. Exemplo: [Dijkstra em Java](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html).